# Mongoose updateOne() can't pass in options

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, mongoose

I can't seem to be able to pass in options when updating data in mongoose, I just get an error saying `Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)`

The code I'm using is almost identical to the docs. I am using the latest version (8.0.3) of mongoose.

```js
const guild = await guildSchema.findOne({ id: interaction.guildId })
await guild?.updateOne(
        {
            id: interaction.user.id 
        },
        {
            $set: {
                "some.value": true
            }
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: [
                {
                    "i.recipe": "Fried rice",
                    "i.item": { $not: { $regex: "oil" } },
                }
            ]
        }
    )
```

What makes me so frustrated is that acording to the docs (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.updateOne()) this code is fine, but it' still throwing errors.

This method should even take 4 arguments according to the docs:

```
Parameters:

    [filter] «Object»
    [update] «Object|Array» the update command

    [options] «Object»
        [options.multipleCastError] «Boolean» by default, mongoose only returns the first error that occurred in casting the query. Turn on this option to aggregate all the cast errors.

        [options.strict] «Boolean|String» overwrites the schemas strict mode option

        [options.upsert=false] «Boolean» if true, and no documents found, insert a new document

        [options.writeConcern=null] «Object» sets the write concern for replica sets. Overrides the schema-level write concern

        [options.timestamps=null] «Boolean» If set to false and schema-level timestamps are enabled, skip timestamps for this update. Note that this allows you to overwrite timestamps. Does nothing if schema-level timestamps are not set.

        [options.translateAliases=null] «Boolean» If set to true, translates any schema-defined aliases in filter, projection, update, and distinct. Throws an error if there are any conflicts where both alias and raw property are defined on the same object.

    [callback] «Function» params are (error, writeOpResult)
```

Comment: After reading the docs i don't think you can use `arrayFilters` in the options of `updateOne`, you should check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the `Model`, `Document` and `Query` classes in mongoose. However, the `Model` class is a subclass of the `Document` class.

You **think** you are using the [`Query.updateOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.updateOne()) which takes 3 parameters and a callback.

You **are actually** using the [`Document.updateOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.updateOne()) which only takes 2 parameter and a callback.

To illustrate:

```js
const guild = await guildSchema.findOne({ id: interaction.guildId })
// guild instanceof mongoose.Model; // true
// guild instanceof mongoose.Document; // true
// guild is now a instance of the Document class because you have executed the query
// and assigned the return value from the promise to a variable
await guild?.updateOne();
// This is now Document.updateOne()
```

I think you should just use [`Model.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOneAndUpdate()) where `Guild` is an instance of a `Model` created using `const Guild = mongoose.model('Guild', guildSchema);`

```js
const guild = await Guild.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            id: interaction.user.id 
        },
        {
            $set: {
                "some.value": true
            }
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: [
                {
                    "i.recipe": "Fried rice",
                    "i.item": { $not: { $regex: "oil" } },
                }
            ],
            new: true
        }
    )
```